# How can I add an icon to switch the mapboxgl style dynamically?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl, mapbox-marker

I want to add an icon as below in the mapboxgl view. Working with Angular2

[image]

When I click the icon it should automatically switch the styles (streets-v9, satelllite-v9)

I am following the link [mapboxgl example](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/popup-on-click/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you see this API method? 
https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map#setstyle

With that you can set a new style for the map when you e.g. click an icon or press a button or what ever you wish.

Take this as a reference to build upon:

https://jsfiddle.net/andi_lo/706pot8L/

```js
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiZmFyYWRheTIiLCJhIjoiTUVHbDl5OCJ9.buFaqIdaIM3iXr1BOYKpsQ';
let map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: 'map',
  style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9', 
  center: [-1.77, 52.73],
  zoom: 3,
});

let icon = document.getElementById('icon');

icon.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
 map.setStyle('mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v9');
}, false)
```

```css
#icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 15px;
  color: black;
}

#map {
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.38.0/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.38.0/mapbox-gl.js"></script>

<div id="map"></div>

<button id="icon">
Switch layers
</button>
```

Comment: It changes successfully. but I got the following error immediately. The layer 'places' does not exist in the map's style and cannot be queried for features.  ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: Map loads but the markers not loaded so getting the above error

Comment: Could you create or modify my fiddle to be more specific about what you have. Can't relate that error to my example.

Comment: In jsfiddle  example also the map style changed but the markers not working due to the above error.

Comment: Its working in jsfiddle. I added map.addLayer() inside the icon.addEventListener('click', function(e) { map.setStyle('mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v9'); }, false)  but not working from my code. Getting Error: Style is not done loading

Comment: There is a on load map event that you can use to prevent code execution befor the styles have been loaded. Just wrap your code with `map.on('load', () => { });`. I updated the jsfiddle with it: https://jsfiddle.net/andi_lo/706pot8L/7/

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a "control" that switches layers. Mapbox-GL-JS doesn't include such a thing, nor is there one listed as a [plugin](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/plugins) (yet).

You should use Mapbox-GL-JS's [iControl](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#icontrol) class to create the control, then add styling and behaviour following Mapbox's instructions:

```
function LayerSwitchControl() { }

LayerSwitchControl.prototype.onAdd = function(map) {
    this._map = map;
    this._container = document.createElement('div');
    this._container.className = 'mapboxgl-ctrl';
    // change this next line to include a layer-switching icon
    this._container.textContent = 'Hello, world';
    return this._container;
};

LayerSwitchControl.prototype.onRemove = function () {
     this._container.parentNode.removeChild(this._container);
     this._map = undefined;
};
```

You'll then need to add code to:

1. Add the control
2. Respond to `click` events as appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

This is my working code,

[image]

This is zoom level control

[image]

Comment: Please avoid answers with images only. Text is always preferred for code.